# Change Contextual Filter's Value

Tags: views

I have a view of some content types set up. Is there a way to filter the view using the URL without using the actual values of the field?  For example, say I have content type with a field that can contain the state using the full name (i.e. Washington, Oregon, California).  I would like to use WA in the contextual filter, not Washington.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use WA as value in contextual filter, if you have set up WA as key value for Washington in the allowed values of state.

Comment: What if its just a plain text field?

Comment: You mean state field is text field, then either you need to use phpcode for contextual filter or you need to add "WA" as state value in textfield.